# one nautilus device went missing, why? and how to fix?

Tags: lvm, block-device, nautilus, gvfs

nautilus devices are provided by `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor`, I've already restarted it but one device is still missing. I also tried `strace` on it, but it only outputs info about mounted devices.

Also, the detection provided by `gvfs-mount -l` comes from that monitor, but where it gathers information from? **If I could determine what is missing/wrong on that detection, may be I could fix it.**

I have another very similar device, both are lvm, I checked both with `lvdisplay -v -m` and there is nothing special about the one that is missing on nautilus.

Despite I can successfully mount it with `kvpm`, nautilus still ignores it.

Update: The device is missing at `tree /dev/disk/` that seems to be populated by udev. So the problem may be fixed by some udev command I think.

Obs.: The missing device had some inode errors but I already fixed them with `fsck -vf /dev/dm-6`. From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11162/30352), `udevadm trigger` and `vgscan --mknodes` also helped on making the device link available again at `/dev/<vg>/` (I guess because I had to hard-reset, it went missing there). I fixed it as I believe the monitor may try to read there too. Anyway nothing changed in nautilus even after re-trying actions I detailed previously.

Comment: a reboot fixed the problem that seems with `udev`...

Comment: I wonder if this question is still useful to someone or I should just delete it?